# Simple way to externally disable bootstrap a:hover color?

Tags: html, css

My question is very simple : Is there a way to externally disable the color bootstrap sets on a:hover elements ?

I'm making a website which uses many different font colors, and I'd prefer not to have a CSS setting for each one.

Until now I've been doing it manually for each case, but I'd still like it to be done by default, since that blue color is really ugly on colored backgrounds.

I've seen someone proposing to do the following :

```
a:hover {
    color: inherit;
}
```

As I expected it, this doesn't work, but I can't find any other way to do it :'(

Do I really need to do this for every color there'll be on the website ?

Comment: if there are different colors then you have to do it manually

Comment: If you set the color elements individually and you want to keep the exact same color on `:hover` you can work out something using `currentColor`: [see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ub17ud3g/)

Comment: But what (relative) color does `currentColor` apply to the element ? I don't really understand how to use it :/

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set a class for each anchor where you would like to use a different hover-over color change.

I.e.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="hover-white">Anchor Text White On Hover</a>
<a href="#" class="hover-red">Anchor Text Red On Hover</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.hover-white:hover {color: white;}
.hover-red:hover {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override property of a original 'a' tag according to your convenience like,

```
a {
    color:#999999 !important;
}

a:hover {
    color:#111111 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there doesn't seem to be a "universal" way of doing this, I decided to go in the `styles.css`file (from Bootstrap) and comment link 1744, which applies the color on `hover` and on `focus` of a link.

I don't really like to touch files I haven't created myself, but I guess this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use css:

```
a:hover {
  color: 
}
```

Or if you downloaded the bootstrap css file, locate the section where **a** is at and comment it out or delete it.  Hope that helps :)